# Index not being used in "group by" clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a query in postgres but I have a problem where the index I created is not being used. I have two tables `conversations` and `conversation_items`, they look partially like this:

```
conversations                 conversation_items             
|  id     |   | id  | conversation_id | fields                        |
---------      ------------------------------------------------------
| some_id |   | id1 | some_id         | { "timestamp": "2017-09-29" }
| other   |   | id2 | some_id         | { "timestamp": "2017-09-28" }
```

I would like to get a result where for a given conversation id I get the following result, where the item ids are ordered chronologically by the items timestamp.

```
| id     | some_other_conversation_field | items   |
----------------------------------------------------
|some_id | some information about convo  | id2,id1 |
```

This is the query:

```
select conversations.id, array_to_string(array_agg(conversation_items.id), ',')
from conversations
left join (    
select * from conversation_items
order by (conversation_items.fields ->> 'timestamp')) as conversation_items
on conversations.id = conversation_items.conversation_id
WHERE (conversations.id='blab')
group by conversations.id
limit 1;
```

And here is the query plan:
[image]

I tried running explain with just the inner select and it worked as expected and the index was used.

Comment: perhaps you should begin with the table structure and what you want to achieve..

Comment: I have updated my answer with partial information about the tables and what I'd like to achieve

Comment: Please post the execution plan as plain, [formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) text. If you want to obfuscate table names, you can upload it to http://explain.depesz.com/ and enable the "I want this plan to be obfuscated" option. The execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)`** would be more helpful also. All steps in the plan use an index - why do you think it does not use an index?

Comment: What data type is `conversations.id`

Comment: Unrelated, but: `array_to_string(array_agg(conversation_items.id), ',')` can be simplified to `string_agg(conversation_items.id, ',')`

Comment: its not `group by`, but `limit 1` - known feature often very effective - remove limit and see the plan. also - you can always `set enable_bitmapscan to off` to compare plans...

Comment: please avoid screenshots, you can erase your filter at depesz, still giving us wonderful ability to copy paste and Ctrl+F in your plan...